# Run event if return from external application

Tags: c#, winforms

I have following function, it returns me the selected control of the application if I tab back to my application.
Now I want to call an event of the selected control.

Actually I only want to select the text of the selected textbox control if the application is selected.
For this task I wrote some _Enter Events, but they wont get fired if you tab back to your application

So I tried to get the active control of the application and fire the event I prepared but I fail running the event. The active control can be one of 10 textboxes. Please help.

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    //react to switching from an external application
    const int WM_ACTIVATEAPP = 0x001C;
    switch (m.Msg)
    {
        case WM_ACTIVATEAPP:
            {
                if (m.WParam.ToInt32() == 1)
                {
                    //null blocker
                    var temp = this.ActiveControl;
                    if (temp != null)
                    {
                        //if you have a splitcontainer, it is always the active control...
                        if (temp.GetType() == typeof(SplitContainer))
                        {
                            var containerControl = (SplitContainer)ActiveControl;
                            if (containerControl.ActiveControl is TextBox)
                            {
                                //how can i call the _Enter event of the selected control?
                                ((TextBox)containerControl.ActiveControl).Enter += ???;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
    }
    // proceed with default processing
    base.WndProc(ref m);  
}
```

Events are all the same:

```
private void tB_IMEI_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tB_IMEI.SelectionStart = 0;
    tB_IMEI.SelectionLength = tB_IMEI.TextLength;
}
```

EDIT:
BugFinder's comment did the trick.
Found an old Event for Form Activate but it was before the implementation of the SplitContainer. 
I fixed it to work with the SplitContainer Control. 
Thanks Bugfinder!

Working solution:

```
private void focusAllTheText(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox myBox = ((TextBox)sender);
    myBox.SelectAll();
}
private void SearchProvision_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ActiveControl != null && ActiveControl is SplitContainer)
        focusAllTheText(((SplitContainer)ActiveControl).ActiveControl, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Comment: surely the forms activate event triggers though